# How do I create a GraphQL query for DynamoDB

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

My DynamoDB table 'EventChat' has 'eventId' as the partition key and 'createdOn' as Sort Key. I am using AppSync and Apollo client to query the database.
I would like to get all items for a certain 'eventId' and items created BETWEEN two createdOn dates.
What should my Schema and Query and Request Mapping Template look like?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

{
"version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "Query",
"query" : {
"expression" : "eventId = :eventId AND createdOn BETWEEN :t1 AND :t2",
"expressionValues" : {
":eventId": { "S" : "${context.arguments.eventId}" },
":t1": { "S" : "${context.arguments.t1}" },
":t2": { "S" : "${context.arguments.t2}" },
}
}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).